# What is wrong with my CountHeight function for binary trees (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

```
var CountHeight = function(root){
    if(root == null){
       console.log("NULL!")
       return 0;
    }

    leftheight = CountHeight(root.left);
    rightheight = CountHeight(root.right);
    if (leftheight > rightheight){
        return leftheight + 1;
    } else if(rightheight > leftheight){
        return rightheight + 1;
    } else if(rightheight == leftheight){
        return leftheight + 1;
    }

}
```

Each root has a left and right value that points to another tree.

I tried to test out this function by plugging in a tree (I know the function takes a parameter called root but I'm basically passing a tree into it). The tree I passed on looked something like this:

```
(root)10: (leftofroot)left: 4 - left: null right: 8
(rightofroot)right: 15 - left: null right: null
```

If you cant follow the above diagram, I'm basically adding the following nodes ot my tree: 10, 4, 15, 8

Ok, so when I passed my tree into the function, I got the value of 2, but clearly my tree has a height of 3. The node 8 being the only node with that has a depth of 3.

So can someone tell me what's going wrong with my function?

PS: I'm struggling, if my question is too confusing, can someone give me another function that finds the height of a tree when I pass a tree into it.

Thanks!

```
var testBST = new BST();
testBST.addNode(10);
testBST.addNode(4);
testBST.addNode(15);
testBST.addNode(8);

console.log(testBST);
console.log(CountHeight(testBST));
```

Comment: You need to declare those variables `leftheight` and `rightheight` inside the function with `var` or `let`.

Comment: POINTY OMG THANKS SO MUCH WHY AM I SO DUMB SORRY FOR BOTHERING STACKOVERFLOW COMMUNITY IGNORE ME

Comment: OMG, I've been using too much python, RIP ME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shrink the later conditions by using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for getting maximum depth of left and right side.

```
function countHeight(root) {
    return root
        ? 1 + Math.max(countHeight(root.left), countHeight(root.right))
        : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea!